# dynamic theme color

Tags: android

i want to use dynamic theme color and get the color from server please what is the best approach to do that,and if i can edit color attribute in xml from java how can i do that.

Comment: you cannot change the content of the XML as it is compiled.

Answer (score 2):

What are you attempting to change the colour of? A layout background colour?

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
int color = Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 255); // Use your values from the server here
ll.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Comment: but if i want to set the color for each control this will be very hard work and i search for a good solution...

Comment: I don't believe there is any other way to handle it. If you want this level of runtime customisation, it's the price you'll have to pay.